# Doctrine generate-migrations-diff and migrate

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, command-line-interface, migration

I have tried to execute the cli command ./doctrine generate-migrations-diff and a version file has been created correctly in the right folder.

The message is: **generate-migrations-diff - Generated migration classes successfully from difference**

Then I try to execute another cli command ./doctrine migrate and a message appears to me saying: **migrate - migrated successfully to version #1** but when I open the class any modification have been done. Why?

This is the version1 file:

```
<?php

class Version1 extends Doctrine_Migration_Base
{
public function up()
{
    $this->removeColumn('addresses', 'address_test');
}

public function down()
{
    $this->addColumn('addresses', 'address_test', 'string', '', array(
         'fixed' => '0',
         'unsigned' => '',
         'primary' => '',
         'notnull' => '1',
         'autoincrement' => '',
         ));
}
}

?>
```

This is the YAML. **I have deleted the field: address_test**

```
Addresses:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: addresses
  columns:
    address_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    address:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    city:
      type: string(150)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    code:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    country_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    base:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    latitude:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    longitude:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    customer_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
```

This is the BaseAddresses class generated by the **migrate** command:
    bindComponent('Addresses', 'doctrine');

```
/**
 * BaseAddresses
 * 
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 * 
 * @property integer $address_id
 * @property string $address
 * @property string $city
 * @property string $code
 * @property integer $country_id
 * @property integer $base
 * @property string $latitude
 * @property string $longitude
 * @property integer $customer_id
 * @property Countries $Countries
 * @property Customers $Customers
 * 
 * @package    ##PACKAGE##
 * @subpackage ##SUBPACKAGE##
 * @author     ##NAME## <##EMAIL##>
 * @version    SVN: $Id: Builder.php 7490 2010-03-29 19:53:27Z jwage $
 */
abstract class BaseAddresses extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('addresses');
        $this->hasColumn('address_id', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('address', 'string', null, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('city', 'string', 150, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '150',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('code', 'string', 20, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '20',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('country_id', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('base', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'default' => '0',
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '1',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('latitude', 'string', 20, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '20',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('longitude', 'string', 20, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '20',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('customer_id', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasOne('Countries', array(
             'local' => 'country_id',
             'foreign' => 'country_id'));

        $this->hasOne('Customers', array(
             'local' => 'customer_id',
             'foreign' => 'customer_id',
             'onDelete' => 'CASCADE'));
    }
}
```

In some website I have read that I have to execute the command: **build-all** in order to generate a version updated of the class addresses but I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'web63db1.#sql-3e6_11d' (errno: 121). Failing Query: "ALTER TABLE addresses ADD CONSTRAINT addresses_customer_id_customers_customer_id FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE". Failing Query: ALTER TABLE addresses ADD CONSTRAINT addresses_customer_id_customers_customer_id FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

What have I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Migrations are only for changing your Database, not your model classes. You need to build your model classes afterwards.

So your normal way of working will be:

1. Change your schema.yml
2. Create your Migration file (generate-migrations-diff)
3. Run your migration against the database (migrate), your database should be changed now
4. Update your model-classes (build-all)

Comment: Hi Timo, after the migrate command I have executed the build-all but I get this error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1007 Can't create database 'mydb'; database exists.

Answer (score 1):

As I can't comment, let me modify Timo's answer:

1. Change Your schema.yml
2. Create Migration File (doctrine:generate-migrations-diff) (Note: this is comparing schema against *Class files*)
3. Run your Migration (doctrine:migrate)(this runs the migrations based on the migration version number in your database)
4. Build your class files. (doctrine:build --all-classes **OR** doctrine:build-model & doctrine:build-forms & doctrine:build-filters) (Note: this will build all your class files but will not try to update your database.)

I highly recommend backing up your database before running any migrations for the first time. If a migration fails (i.e. because you typoed your schema), you can end up with a database that is stuck between migrations and will need to be scrapped. I usually, backup my test-db and then import the live db to test the migration on. I'm more than slightly terrified of failing a migration on the live server.

Its important to note that the 'doctrine:generate-migrations-diff' compares the schema.yml to your currently generated class files. *Don't build your classes before generating your migration*

To deploy on a server, you will need to upload your schema.yml and your new migration files. Then just do steps 3 & 4 (and then clear your cache as a matter of habit) and you're good to go.